# Как задать такую тень картинке?

Tags: css

кака задать такую тень картинке?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C помощью CSS3. Например как [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/laustdeleuran/JjZAA/)

Тут описан [процесс создания теней](http://themousepotatowebsite.co.za/box-shadow-and-css-transforms-a-future-without-pngs/)